# Crash using fast enumarion: __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124 inside a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm getting very random crashes with the error: `__NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124` when performing a for loop when an object fails to download. I believe I know why, but I would like reassurance to see if this is indeed the issue, because it isn't a recreatable bug very easily. This is the code I'm performing. Doing some research, it appears I'm mutating something while it was changed, but this is why I created the: `newArrayCopy` `NSMutableArray`, to try to avoid this issue.

```
NSMutableArray *newArrayCopy = [self.dataSource objectForKey:@"Messages"];

for (NSDictionary *sub in [self.dataSource objectForKey:@"Messages"])
{
    if ([[sub objectForKey:@"MessageID"]isEqualToString:[self.downloadDictionary objectForKey:@"MessageID"]])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *updatedDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:sub];
        [updatedDict setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"Bypass"];

        [newArrayCopy replaceObjectAtIndex:[newArrayCopy indexOfObject:sub] withObject:updatedDict];

        // This line below is perhaps the culprit?
        [self.dataSource setObject:newArrayCopy forKey:@"Messages"];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
     }
}
```

Is the problem occuring because I'm setting the `self.dataSource` within the if statement before the for loop finishes?

Comment: Be careful! Should NOT modify `NSMutableArray` while enumerating it. You should make a copy to do it

Comment: yeah, here:`[self.dataSource setObject:newArrayCopy forKey:@"Messages"];`

Comment: @vikingosegundo Should I break the loop after `reloadData`

Comment: You won't make it there.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Can you explain why it wont reach there?

Comment: because you try to modify the enumerated array, this will crash.

Comment: thats why I proposed to enumerate a copy. than the rest of code should work. and you can break out.

Comment: Right, I added the copy and all is well, so the break will just stop the loop from continuing since I only need to find the one object

Comment: but maybe you could shorten that code drastically by using some filtering on the array. check `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`, or `indexOfObjectPassingTest:`

Comment: and btw: I had an idea for email conformation. It is not needed to send out an email. the smtp server can be ask for the given email address if an account exists.

Comment: @vikingosegundo So basically if the email bounces, it's a bogus email?

Comment: no, there are commands to ask the server if a account exists directly. no sending involved. http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/

Comment: `NSMutableArray *newArrayCopy = [self.dataSource objectForKey:@"Messages"];` does not create a copy. Is that the source of your confusion?

Comment: Actually it does gives me a copy, confirmed in an NSLog, I have the array duplicated..

Comment: No, it gives you a new reference to the same memory. You have to _explicitly_ copy objects.

Comment: what about: `NSMutableArray *newArrayCopy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:];`

Comment: Josh is right. if you send `mutableCopy` there, you don't need to create another copy.

Comment: That does create a copy, yes.

Comment: wth, wonder why its been working then for so long

Comment: maybe the if statement was never triggered?

Comment: isn't the first line giving you a warning that you write an nasty to a nsmutablearray variable?

Comment: No warnings or errors at all

Comment: no, of course not. in message sending it won't yield a warning.

Comment: @vikingosegundo That email thing is pretty cool, too bad we run the risk of being IP blocked though :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying the array that is being enumerated, this isn't allowed. you can overcome it by enumerating a copy

```
for (NSDictionary *sub in [[self.dataSource objectForKey:@"Messages"] copy]) {
    //....
}
```